# How to solve runtime identity configuration issue in AspNet Core?

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am creating an application using .Net Core 3 and using AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore for Creating User Roles but after writing command for seeding database i am getting an run time error.

My Startup.cs Class

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => {
            opt.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });
        services.AddCors(opt => {
            opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy => {
                policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            });
        });
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddMediatR(typeof(List.Handler).Assembly);
        services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                .AddFluentValidation(cfg => cfg.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Create>());

        var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>();
        var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);
        identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
        identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();
    }
```

`

My Data Context Class is

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
          public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
          {
          }

          public DbSet<Value> Values { get; set; }
          public DbSet<Activity> Acitivities {get;set;}

          protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
          {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<Value>()
                 .HasData(
                     new Value {Id = 1, Name = "Biraz1"},
                     new Value {Id = 2, Name = "Biraz2"},
                     new Value {Id = 3, Name = "Biraz3"}
                 );
          }
    }
```

My AppUser class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Domain
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and my Program.cs class is

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            //Create database based on our Migrations
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                try 
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
                    context.Database.Migrate();
                    Seed.SeedData(context, userManager).Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured during migration");
                }
            }
            host.Run();
            
        }
```

The Error I am getting :

```
An error occurred while starting the application.
AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)

AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter<TContainerBuilder>.CreateServiceProvider(object containerBuilder)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
API.Program.Main(string[] args) in Program.cs
+
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

Show raw exception details
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)

Show raw exception details
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)

Show raw exception details
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)

Show raw exception details
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)

Show raw exception details
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)

Show raw exception details
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Domain.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[Domain.AppUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
```

and my AppUser Class is

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Domain
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this is from online course I know and the issue is due to he is using net core 2.2.
to solve to this problem add this at startup.cs:

```
    services.TryAddSingleton<ISystemClock, SystemClock>();
```

so your final code should be like:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<ISystemClock, SystemClock>();
var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>();
var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);
identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();
```

The missing error idk why you hide it

> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to
> activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.`blablalbla`